# Is there optimization for this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This query works fine but it takes too large time to be executed. Its running on xampp localhost.

simply I want to select webpage.id where word= "somthing" AND word
!= " another somthing"

what I mean is, if you search on Google you can use that shortcut 
"python -cat"
that means get all links that contain word "python" and not contain word "cat".

```
SELECT webpage.title, word.title, word.id, webpage.title, webpage.id, webpage.link, wordpage.wordID, wordpage.id, wordpage.type, wordpage.pageID
FROM SE_word AS word
INNER JOIN se_wordpage AS wordpage ON wordpage.wordID = word.id
INNER JOIN se_webpage AS webpage ON wordpage.pageID = webpage.id
WHERE word.title = "python"

AND webpage.id NOT IN (    
SELECT WP.id
FROM se_webpage AS WP
INNER JOIN se_wordpage AS WOP ON WP.id = WOP.pageID
INNER JOIN se_word AS W ON W.id = WOP.wordID
WHERE W.title = "cat"
)
GROUP BY webpage.id
ORDER BY webpage.title DESC
```

It's simple search engine for example

```
table se_Word is
**id   |  title**
1   |   "game"
2   |   "java"
3   |   "python"

table se_WebPage is
**id   |  title**
1   |   "www.ABCDEF.com"
2   |   "www.ABCDR.net"
3   |   "www.ABC.com"


table se_WordPage is
**id   |  pageID   |   wordID**
1   |   1   |   1
2   |   2   |   3
3   |   3   |   3
3   |   2   |   1
```

the result should be webpage.id = 3

[here is](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41343544/se_db.sql) creation script
Is there any optimization for it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Provide an execution plan with `EXPLAIN` 2. Provide all table schemas

Comment: @Strawberry do you mean the sub-query ?
I think the values of columns in the main query is differ than the values of sub-query

Comment: you haven't added neither: 1. `EXPLAIN` 2. `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: @zerkms here is creation script https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41343544/se_db.sql

Comment: just add explain and schemas here

Comment: @zerkms what I mean is, if you search on Google you can use that shortcut "python -cat" that means get all links that contain word "python" and not contain word "cat".
and this is schemas https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41343544/tables.PNG
thanks in advance

Comment: it's not a schema. The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` contains the whole table definition, including indexes. `EXPLAIN` demonstrates the current query plan. It's all **REQUIRED** to know to optimize queries. But I'm too tired to ask it for the 5th time. Have fun ;-)

Comment: I've attached it 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41343544/se_db.sql
is it ?

Comment: put `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for every table **IN THE QUESTION**

Answer (score 0):

Using "not in" is slow.  If your database supports the syntax here are two faster ways.

```
where not exists
(your subquery)
```

or

```
where webpage.id in
(select id
 from se_webpage
 except
 select id
 from 
 the rest is as per your existing subquery
)
```

With some db engines you use the keyword "minus" instead of "except".

Comment: MySQL supports neither MINUS nor EXCEPT.

Comment: Not exists works fine but the time is the nearby the same ! thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can get rid of the NOT IN piece then you should see a healthy performance boost. Try using these two equivalent statements as an example of how to rewrite your statement.

Statement 1:

```
select ID, PreferredMethods 
from ContactPrefs 
where type='Mail' and 
ID NOT IN 
(select ID from ContactPrefs where type='Email' or type='Phone' or type='Text')
```

Statement 1 is equivalent to Statement 2, but Statment 2 will perform better:

```
select ID, PreferredMethods from ContactPrefs c1 
left outer join
ContactPrefs c2 on c1.ID=c2.ID
and (c2.type='Email' or c2.type='Phone' or c2.type='Text')
where c1.type='Mail' and c2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to consider a solution along [these lines](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,507748,507839#msg-507839) - provided some months ago by someone in a different forum (I know, I know) altogether.

In addition, the first part of your query would make more sense (to me anyway) written like this (note the absence of a GROUP BY clause - that's deliberate)...

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.title p_title
              , w.title w_title
              , w.id w_id
              , p.id p_id
              , p.link
              , wp.id
              , wp.type
           FROM SE_word w
           JOIN se_wordpage wp 
             ON wp.wordID = w.id
           JOIN se_webpage p 
             ON p.id = wp.pageID
          WHERE w.title = "python"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not tested this query, but I think it might do the job. Please, let me know if it works without errors.

Based on your original query, I just removed the subquery, added in the `WHERE` clause the "cat" title and added a `HAVING` clause to filter after the `GROUP BY` the webpages that were selected just one time and this selection refers to the "python" title.

I'm assuming that you **never** assign one given word to one given webpage multiple times.

```
SELECT 
  webpage.title, 
  word.title, 
  word.id, 
  webpage.title, 
  webpage.id, 
  webpage.link, 
  wordpage.wordID, 
  wordpage.id, 
  wordpage.type, 
  wordpage.pageID
FROM se_word AS word 
INNER JOIN se_wordpage AS wordpage 
  ON wordpage.wordID = word.id 
INNER JOIN se_webpage AS webpage 
  ON wordpage.pageID = webpage.id 
WHERE word.title IN ("cat", "python") 
GROUP BY webpage.id 
HAVING 
  COUNT(webpage.id) = 1 
  AND word.title = "python" 
ORDER BY webpage.title DESC;
```

Hope it works well and helps you! Good bye.

**EDIT**

I tested my query (MySQL 5.5.22) and it seems to be working fine! This is my table structure and data:

Table **se_word**:

```
 ---- -------- 
| id | title  |
 ---- -------- 
|  1 | game   |
|  2 | java   |
|  3 | python |
|  4 | cat    |
 ---- --------
```

Table **se_webpage**:

```
 ---- ------ ----------- ------ --------------------- 
| id | link | title     | freq | date                |
 ---- ------ ----------- ------ --------------------- 
|  1 | NULL | aaaaa.com |    0 | 2013-05-15 22:27:40 |
|  2 | NULL | bbbbb.com |    0 | 2013-05-15 22:27:40 |
|  3 | NULL | ccccc.com |    0 | 2013-05-15 22:27:40 |
|  4 | NULL | ddddd.com |    0 | 2013-05-15 22:27:40 |
 ---- ------ ----------- ------ ---------------------
```

Table **se_wordpage**:

```
 ---- -------- -------- ------ 
| id | wordID | pageID | type |
 ---- -------- -------- ------ 
|  1 |      3 |      1 |      |
|  2 |      3 |      2 |      |
|  3 |      3 |      3 |      |
|  4 |      3 |      4 |      |
|  5 |      4 |      2 |      |
|  6 |      4 |      4 |      |
 ---- -------- -------- ------
```

As the "**python**" word refers to all the webpages and the "**cat**" word refers to the second and fourth webpages, the expected output (as far as I understood) should be the first and the third webpages (with some more data). So, the query works great!

**Output**:

```
 ----------- -------- ---- ----------- ---- ------ -------- ---- ------ -------- 
| title     | title  | id | title     | id | link | wordID | id | type | pageID |
 ----------- -------- ---- ----------- ---- ------ -------- ---- ------ -------- 
| ccccc.com | python |  3 | ccccc.com |  3 | NULL |      3 |  3 |      |      3 |
| aaaaa.com | python |  3 | aaaaa.com |  1 | NULL |      3 |  1 |      |      1 |
 ----------- -------- ---- ----------- ---- ------ -------- ---- ------ --------
```

Look that the columns are in the same order as in the query statement.

Let me know if something is wrong.

Comment: `HAVING 
  COUNT(webpage.id) = 1 `
ERROR >

Comment: My fault, sorry. The HAVING clause goes before the ORDER BY. Can you, please, try again the edited query?

Comment: First of all thank you much for that effort, you code runs well but what I meant is, if search on Google you can apply that shortcut 
"python -cat"
that mean get all links that contain word python and not contain word cat. you got it ?